# Cannot reference public object in another class, please look at my source and let me know what I'm doing wrong

Tags: c#, random, public, monogame

I'm learning C# and I'm currently playing with Monogame. What I'm trying to do is declare a public instance of the System.Random class called "randVar" in my Game1 class and then access it from my Testz (derived from Sprite) class. This is not working, it tells me "The name 'randVar' does not exist in the current context.' I'm scratching my head trying to figure out why, because randVar is public I thought I should be able to access it.

My sourcecode is https://gist.github.com/4225880.

Comment: Please have a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) to improve the quality of your question.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to access the `randVar` member of the `Game1` class, you have to first have an instance of the class.  It's the same as any other public member of a class.  It currently doesn't exist within the scope of the `Testz` class.  If you're just wanting a random number, you should just do `Random randVar = new Random()` inside your `Testz` class.

Comment: randVar is an instance of the System.Rand class.

Comment: Right, but it's a public member of the `Game1` class.  To access it, you'll need to create an instance of `Game1`, and then call the `randVar`.  Something like `Game1 game = new Game1();  game.randVar.Next();`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference instance variables defined in one class from another without instantiating the first class in the second. You can do the following in your `TestZ` class:

```
Game1 oGame1 = new Game1();
```

Then you can do:

```
location.X = oGame1.randVar.Next(0,100) * .01f * screenBounds.Width;
```

Answer (score 0):

You define randVar in in Game1 but use it TestZ.  Just move the definition into TestZ or better yet Sprite.

Also, you should know that Random is not thread safe.  So its better to have each class keep its instance.

Comment: +1 I like all the comments in your code.  So I countered the -1 vote on your question.

Comment: When dealing with Sprites, one typically has multiple threads controlling the sprite(s).  A static Random variable as some people have recommended will get the code to compile, but will NOT work correctly.  Google turn this http://www.albahari.com/threading/ up.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yay for learning. I moved the creation of the random object into my sprite class, but now all three testz sprites exhibit the exact same "random" behavior, it looks like they're all using the same random numbers.

Comment: As usual Jon Skeet has the answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785744/how-do-i-seed-a-random-class-to-avoid-getting-duplicate-random-values).  Basically your spites all havethe same random seed.  Use Jon's RandomHelper to initialise the sprite's randVar.

Comment: Thank you so much, that link was very informative. You're incredibly helpful! I've refactored and it's working beautifully.

Comment: No worries.  Accepting my answer is thee accepted way of saying thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add the `static` modifier to your variable's declaration:

```
public static Random randVar = new Random();
```

Comment: This worked. I guess I don't understand why that is necessary but I'll do some reading on access modifiers. I apologize if I seem like a bumbling idiot.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Keep it up.

Comment: Sorry @Alex, but -1.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049467/is-c-sharp-random-number-generator-thread-safe

Comment: That's what SO is all about.  But it did get OP code to compile!