# Random number behaves weird, not fully random

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

In my .NET game my rand function that are determining how much damage each out of the players five characters should take, however the 1st one always seems to be at the bottom of the scale and the last one at the top. So in my `Character[0]` the damage is rarely more than 1 more than the minimum rand value, and for each `Character` on higher index the damage taken is only randomized from higher up the scale.

```
public int GetDamage(int low, int high)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int rand = r.Next(low, high);
    return rand;
}
```

This is the randomizer I use. Then I update the health left like this:

```
int Damage = GetDamage(3, 10);
Characters[Target].Health = Characters[Target].Health - Damage;
```

In this example dmg is divided like this:

```
Number 1: 3-4
Number 2: 4-6
Number 3: 5-7
Number 4: 7-8
Number 5: 8-9
```

Comment: Oh really? An non-seeded random generator is not really random?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar It is technically seeded, just 'badly'.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785744/how-do-i-seed-a-random-class-to-avoid-getting-duplicate-random-values

Comment: No need for the sarcasm though.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1785821/580951

Comment: How would seeding make it "more" random? The real problem is, that there will be multiple instances of `Random` created, possibly with the *same* seed (Milliseconds) producing the same sequence of pseudo random numbers. Rule of Thumb: have *one* instance of `Random` for your whole application except when you know exactly why you would need more than one.

Comment: @Tom It wasn't against you or your programming skills - I just think that the `Random` class is not suited to generate real random numbers.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar. My bad then, must have misunderstood it. However it works well with Tim Schmelter/KingCronus' suggestions.

Comment: I do wish language designers would call it "PseudoRandom()" to avoid confusion sometimes.

Comment: @KingCronus That's redundant, as anyone programming should already know that, as an implication of the difficulties in generating random numbers, they can only be _pseudo_ at best.

Comment: @GrantThomas, I disagree. Search for related questions on here; there are plenty of programmers who don't know this. Not everybody was born a CS Major.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to reuse the same random instance otherwise you won't get really *random* values since it is created with the current time as seed. If you call `GetDamage` very fast(e.g. in a loop) you will get always the same values.

So either use a field/property in the class of `GetDamage` or pass the random instance to the method.

```
private Random _rnd = new Random();
public int GetDamage(int low, int high)
{
    int rand = _rnd.Next(low, high);
    return rand;
}
```

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx)

> The random number generation starts from a seed value. If the same
>   seed is used repeatedly, the same series of numbers is generated. One
>   way to produce different sequences is to make the seed value
>   time-dependent, thereby producing a different series with each new
>   instance of Random. By default, the parameterless constructor of the
>   Random class uses the system clock to generate its seed value, while
>   its parameterized constructor can take an Int32 value based on the
>   number of ticks in the current time. However, because the clock has
>   finite resolution, using the parameterless constructor to create
>   different Random objects in close succession creates random number
>   generators that produce identical sequences of random numbers.    **This
>   problem can be avoided by creating a single Random object rather than
>   multiple ones.**

Comment: As a side note: When using the same `Random` object on multiple `Threads`, the `Random` should be synchronized, or else it will return only `0`.

Comment: Didn't know `Random` is pre-seeded from the current time +1 for the good example.

Comment: @Nolonar Waiting for the timer to go out :P I have accepted answers on all my previous questions :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to make your `Random` instance static, this seeds it once and thereafter you will get a more random looking number.

```
static Random r = new Random();

public int GetDamage(int low, int high)
{
    int rand = r.Next(low, high);
    return rand;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to seed the random number generator.

See: [How do I seed a random class to avoid getting duplicate random values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785744/how-do-i-seed-a-random-class-to-avoid-getting-duplicate-random-values)

Literally hundreds of this question on here, have a look around.