# How to Generate random numbers without the same number

Tags: c#, unique-key

Can you please give me the answer how can i generate numbers without the same numbers ?
Because i am creating a lottery program, and i want my program having no same numbers because the lottery is not having an output that has the same numbers.

Comment: Search for "shuffle".

Comment: Why do you say that, that the lottery does not have the same numbers.  Do you mean not the same number in a set of numbers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i seed a random class to avoid getting duplicate random values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785744/how-do-i-seed-a-random-class-to-avoid-getting-duplicate-random-values)

Comment: @Hogan Surely you know how lotteries work. Combination of `k` number out of `n` without replacement.

Comment: @Hogan When you have a lottery you're selecting, say, 5 numbers between 1 and 100, but those 5 numbers should be unique.  The lottery is never 1,1,1,1,1.

Comment: Yes guys, I answered that question, I'm still not sure it was what was being asked, but I answered what the question seemed to be asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select a random N elements from List<T> in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48087/select-a-random-n-elements-from-listt-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want to do is use the Set specialized collection.  Pick a random item left in the Set and then remove it from the set.  Pick another.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with multithreading and random initialization.

```
static Random r = new Random();
static IEnumerable<int> Randoms(int max)
{
    while(true)
        yield return r.Next(max);
}
```

Usage:

```
var items = Randoms(50).Distinct().Take(10).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You now you need to put it in a recursive method, but here is a simple way.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
        numbers.Add(1);
        numbers.Add(2);
        numbers.Add(3);
        numbers.Add(4);
        numbers.Add(5);
        numbers.Add(6);
        numbers.Add(7);

        Random rand = new Random();

        var numbersSfle = numbers.OrderBy(item => rand.Next()).ToList();
        Console.Write(numbersSfle[0].ToString());
        numbers.RemoveAt(0);


        numbersSfle = numbers.OrderBy(item => rand.Next()).ToList();
        Console.Write(numbersSfle[0].ToString());
        numbers.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

The fiddle:

http://ideone.com/p39Lhg