# Random Functions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have functions which generate random examples but I need this functions to be random as well. thanks in advance ;)

```
public void generateExample()
{
    x = Random.Range(0, 10);
    y = Random.Range(0, 10 - x);
    _text.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = x.ToString() + " + " + y.ToString() + " =";
    resultNum = x + y;

}

public void generateExample2()
{

    x = Random.Range(0, 10);
    y = Random.Range(0, x);
    _text.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = x.ToString() + " - " + y.ToString() + " =";
    resultNum = x - y;
}
```

Comment: u want to call both function randomly? please calarify

Comment: Is it possible that this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785744/how-do-i-seed-a-random-class-to-avoid-getting-duplicate-random-values

Comment: yes I want both functions to be random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
y = new Random();
x = y.Range(0, 1);

if (x == 0)
{
  generateExample();
}
else if (x == 1)
{
  generateExample2();
}
```

Comment: thank you so much ;) forgot to put it in void update so it was generating only + examples . thanks man you really helped me